# " null value in column "version" violates not-null" on db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I am trying to rebuild my development database from bare metal and am getting a strange error that I've not seen before.  I cant seem to track down the cause.  Here are the commands I am running and the results:

```
rake db:drop

rake db:create

rake db:migrate:status
  Schema migrations table does not exist yet.

rake db:migrate
  ==  CreateUser: migrating =====================================================
  -- create_table(:user)
     -> 0.0264s
  ==  CreateUser: migrated (0.0267s) ============================================

  rake aborted!
  An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

  PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "version" violates not-null constraint
  DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null).
  : INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" DEFAULT VALUES
  /home/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:774:in `async_exec'
```

I am fairly certain I have not modified the user migration file since last time I successfully migrated it.  Have any of you seen this error before and resolved it?

Comment: Do you have a migration that does not start with timestamps by any chance? It looks like Postgre SQL is trying to insert a null value for the column `version` of your `schema` table... -- also, do you know what is `DEFAULT VALUES`?

Comment: What does that migration do?

Comment: The version insert is the start of the file name (usualy `timestamp_migration_name.rb`). I bet your migration file name starts with `_`.

Comment: I deleted the first migration and tried again without it, but get the same error.  The files are named correctly, i.e., 20140306165659_create_user.rb.  It does not appear to be an issue with the migration files themselves.

Comment: Figured this out finally.  As usual, its a stupid programmer's error.  I had been working on an extension to ActiveRecord for my project and that extension was the source of this error. Once removed, migrations are working again.  Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: Could you elaborate on what fixed this? I've had the same problem for months now and can't track it down...

Comment: Sorry, just noticed your comment. In my case, I think I had tried to override the initialize method in my extension code.  I think I ran into this problem - [don't override initialize in ActiveRecord](http://blog.dalethatcher.com/2008/03/rails-dont-override-initialize-on.html).

Comment: This seems to be not reproducible and probably should be closed, per above comment: _I had been working on an extension to ActiveRecord for my project and that extension was the source of this error. Once removed, migrations are working again._

Comment: Not sure what reason to choose when closing?  The choices I get do not apply to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try :text instead of :string in migration.